# Socket got error when use angular2 at MAC OS environment.

Tags: angular, socket.io, centos6

my app use nodeJs , angular2 , socket.io .

Nodejs 6
Angular 2
socket at server 1.6.0 at client 1.6.0
MAC OS is my environment

I tried to make a chat room :

add a message to a chat room.
switch another chat room.
switch back to first room. Then nothing to display.
I've got chrome console messages.

> zone.js:1382 GET
>   http:/X.X.X.X:YYYY/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LYvYIgZ
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

My code run well on some computer , but I got error when run on some other computers .

I don't know why . Thanks for help !

Comment: Welcome to SO, it usually helps to post some of your code.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on guidelines.